# Mutual recursion with many parameters

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a bunch of components labeled A-Z... I start by sending each component a value of 1.0 and each component returns a double (say a_0,b_0,..,z_0). Next iteration I send the sum (1.0 + a_0 + ... + z_0) to each component to get 26 new doubles (a_1,...,z_1) and a new value of (1.0 + a_0 + ... +z_0 + ... + a_1 + ... + z_1). The calculation continues in this manner day to day.

The problem is each component is in itself recursive and relies on 20 or so values from previous days. So the most obvious recursive implementation gets messy since each independent path of the component calculation has a massive redundant recursive call.

In my current implementation I separated the components into multiple agents who are responsible for their own state and use message passing to complete the calculation. I'm now in a position where I need to make a change to my model and I'm finding this implementation isn't flexible.

My new idea is to use an immutable object to hold the state of the component where each iteration I'd clone my component object and update the state using a discriminate union. i.e.

```
Component(oldcomponent, [Parameter1(22.0), Parameter14(10.0)])
```

would have the state of 
oldcomponent but update parameters 1 and 14. So that each path of the component calculation would be easy to read since most paths only update a few parameters. And as a bonus I can separate the calculation into a series of functions that that take a list of mutations as input and outputs a new list of mutations.

However, I feel this problem is well suited for a functional language and I'm somewhat deviating from a functional design, which is fine but I'm curious as to how others would go about solving this problem?

**Edit:**

I suppose the discriminate union aspect is pointless when I could use a record with the "with syntax" to pass it around.

Comment: agent-based message passing style looks fine to me - so of course its good design to pass the 20-values arround - why not?

Comment: I'll rethink the agent based approach, I just now need to make a change to my model which involves using parameters spread out across multiple agents and I feel like implementing this change is more complicated then it should be... As far as passing around 20 parameters, when it comes to playing around with my model it starts to feel redundant when I need to add a parameter or two and I find my self updating half a dozen recursive calls to account for it.

Comment: I think it would help to see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question properly then the problem can be modeled using the below code example:

```
//Rec function type to make state full functions
type RecFn = RecF of (double -> double * RecFn)

//State type for component A
type StateA = double
//Component A
let compa = 
    let startState : StateA = 1.0
    let rec run (st:StateA) (i:double) = 
        (i+st) , (RecF (run (st+1.0)))
    RecF (run startState)

//State type for component B
type StateB = double
//Component B
let compb = 
    let startState : StateA = 1.0
    let rec run (st:StateA) (i:double) = 
        (i*st) , (RecF (run (st+1.0)))
    RecF (run startState)

//Main rec function
let rec execute (input : double) (fns : RecFn list) (count:int) = 
    let (vals, newFns) = 
        fns 
        |> List.map (function RecF v -> v input)
        |> List.unzip
    match count with
    | 0 -> vals
    | _ -> 
        let newSum = (vals |> List.sum) + input
        execute newSum newFns (count-1)

//Start with 1.0 as initial value for compa and compb
execute 1.0  [compa; compb] 5
|> printfn "%A"
```

The best way to model your state would be create record types for each of the component (in this example the state was just a double value).
To make it fast you can even use PSeq module while applying the component to the double value to get the list of double values.

I have used count value to make it run 5 times, in case you need to run for many days, you can pass a callback function in place of count and call that callback from execute method each time a new list of double is generated so that the callback can do further processing if required.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is a map-reduce problem that can be solved as follows:

```
> let next components f x =
    1.0 + Array.reduce (+) (Array.map (f x) components);;
val next : 'a [] -> ('b -> 'a -> float) -> 'b -> float
```

The function `f` accepts the input value (e.g. `1.0`) and the component that it must model. Mapping this over each component using the input value gives an array of the results. Reducing over this array using the `+` function sums the results before we add `1.0`.

The next problem you describe is a variant where each component requires its own independent accumulator. This might be written:

```
> let next f (x, accumulators) =
    let ys = Array.map (f x) accumulators
    1.0 + Array.sumBy fst ys, Array.map snd ys;;
val next : 'a [] -> ('b -> 'a -> float) -> 'b -> float
```

where `f` now returns a pair containing the result and accumulator.

Note that purity is not advantageous here. The imperative solution is just:

```
> let next f x (accumulators: _ []) =
    for i=0 to accumulators.Length-1 do
      accumulators.[i] <- f(x, snd accumulators.[i])
    1.0 + Array.sumBy fst accumulators;;
```

where `f` now mutates the accumulator in-place.

> In my current implementation I separated the components into multiple agents who are responsible for their own state and use message passing to complete the calculation

I would not use agents for this. They are for concurrent programming and there is nothing concurrent about this problem.